Could not dispatch a message to the daemon. (Few days ago, this project was working. Now, it's only showing errors.)
The message received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has disappeared.
Build request sent: Build{id=5c200f58-5b01-411a-9f1b-66cd59291749, currentDir=C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Loops_Local\Loops-AI\android}
Attempting to read last messages from the daemon log...
Daemon pid: 9548
log file: C:\Users\DELL.gradle\daemon\7.6.3\daemon-9548.out.log
----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-9548.out.log -----
2024-05-25T11:34:51.849+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 22: received class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build
2024-05-25T11:34:51.855+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection] thread 22: Received non-IO message from client: Build{id=5c200f58-5b01-411a-9f1b-66cd59291749, currentDir=C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Loops_Local\Loops-AI\android}
2024-05-25T11:34:51.865+0545 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler] Received command: Build{id=5c200f58-5b01-411a-9f1b-66cd59291749, currentDir=C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Loops_Local\Loops-AI\android}.
2024-05-25T11:34:51.866+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler] Starting executing command: Build{id=5c200f58-5b01-411a-9f1b-66cd59291749, currentDir=C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Loops_Local\Loops-AI\android} with connection: socket connection from /127.0.0.1:60179 to /127.0.0.1:60191.
2024-05-25T11:34:51.896+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] Command execution: started DaemonCommandExecution[command = Build{id=5c200f58-5b01-411a-9f1b-66cd59291749, currentDir=C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Loops_Local\Loops-AI\android}, connection = DefaultDaemonConnection: socket connection from /127.0.0.1:60179 to /127.0.0.1:60191] after 0.0 minutes of idle
2024-05-25T11:34:51.897+0545 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Marking the daemon as busy, address: [d2b26f0f-1f33-4dc5-834f-c7d732d42fec port:60179, addresses:[localhost/127.0.0.1]]
2024-05-25T11:34:51.897+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Marking busy by address: [d2b26f0f-1f33-4dc5-834f-c7d732d42fec port:60179, addresses:[localhost/127.0.0.1]]
2024-05-25T11:34:51.908+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-05-25T11:34:51.916+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-05-25T11:34:51.926+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-05-25T11:34:51.928+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] resetting idle timer
2024-05-25T11:34:51.929+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon is running. Sleeping until state changes.
2024-05-25T11:34:51.938+0545 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy] Daemon is about to start building Build{id=5c200f58-5b01-411a-9f1b-66cd59291749, currentDir=C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Loops_Local\Loops-AI\android}. Dispatching build started information...
2024-05-25T11:34:51.939+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 24: dispatching org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted@7aaa88fc
2024-05-25T11:34:51.972+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment] Configuring env variables: [PATH, USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE, FLUTTER_HOST, PROCESSOR_LEVEL, SYSTEMDRIVE, SESSIONNAME, ALLUSERSPROFILE, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE, PUB_ENVIRONMENT, VSCODE_PID, PROGRAMFILES, PSMODULEPATH, PROGRAMDATA, DIRNAME, CHOCOLATEYLASTPATHUPDATE, USERNAME, APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL, CMD_LINE_ARGS, VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG, CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME, EXIT_WITH_ERRORLEVEL, FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING, ONEDRIVE, APP_HOME, MINGIT_PATH, PATHEXT, VSCODE_CRASH_REPORTER_PROCESS_TYPE, EFC_18492, SNAPSHOT_PATH, SHARED_BIN, VSCODE_CODE_CACHE_PATH, WINDIR, ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP, HOMEPATH, PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER, PUBLIC, CACHE_DIR, ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN, _SKIP, LOCALAPPDATA, COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86), USERDOMAIN, VSCODE_HANDLES_UNCAUGHT_ERRORS, DART_SDK_PATH, FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING, LOGONSERVER, JAVA_HOME, FLUTTER_TOOLS_DIR, PROMPT, PROGRAMFILES(X86), FLUTTER_ROOT, CHOCOLATEYTOOLSLOCATION, ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE, =C:, APPDATA, PROGRAMW6432, VSCODE_AMD_ENTRYPOINT, SYSTEMROOT, JAVA_EXE, CHOCOLATEYINSTALL, DART, VSCODE_CWD, OS, COMMONPROGRAMW6432, COMPUTERNAME, COMMONPROGRAMFILES, COMSPEC, PROCESSOR_REVISION, CLASSPATH, PYCHARM, APP_BASE_NAME, TEMP, FLUTTER_ALREADY_LOCKED, HOMEDRIVE, USERPROFILE, TMP, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS, KOTLIN, VSCODE_IPC_HOOK]
2024-05-25T11:34:52.115+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] About to start relaying all logs to the client via the connection.
2024-05-25T11:34:52.118+0545 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 9548). The daemon log file: C:\Users\DELL.gradle\daemon\7.6.3\daemon-9548.out.log
2024-05-25T11:34:52.143+0545 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth] Starting build in new daemon [memory: 4 GiB]
2024-05-25T11:34:52.298+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has started executing the build.
2024-05-25T11:34:52.307+0545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=e21c6817-fc9d-4a09-89d1-10c5bfbc51f4,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\DELL.gradle\daemon,pid=9548,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED,-Xmx4G,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
----- End of the daemon log -----
JVM crash log found: file:///C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Local/LoAI/android/hs_err_pid9548.log
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.

Try:



Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

How can I resolve this?

Hi, could you fix this? I'm now having the same problem with "Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly". The strange thing is that this only happens for an amd64 build (arm64 and arm/v7 work without problems in a docker multi-build)

Just disable your Antivirus (ESET I think..)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
